# Грамматика в незамысловатом предложении

Tags: грамматика

Уважаемые знатоки! Помогите, пожалуйста, определиться как правильнее:

> По чем экзамен?

Или же

> По чему экзамен?

Имеется ввиду "По какому предмету будет экзамен?"

Также, чтоб не было вопросов в дальнейшем, укажите, какие правила регулируют данную грамматику.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оба варианта неправильны. Но вариант "по чем" вообще ни в какие ворота не лезет, в то время как в "по чему" по крайней мере падеж правильный (По какому предмету экзамен?), неправильность в том, что вопрос "что?" (по чему?) не может обычно служить заменой вопросу "какой?" (кроме как в именительном падеже во фразах типа "я не тот, что был вчера"), так что ошибка скорее лексическая, но на грани просторечия.

> Также, чтоб не было вопросов в дальнейшем, укажите, какие правила
> регулируют данную грамматику.

Вот этого совсем не понял. Какие правила-то то, что тут регулировать, кроме падежа?

Comment: Для меня «По чему экзамен?» звучит вполне хорошо.